# Sveltekit page change adds HTML at bottom of page

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a Sveltekit Web Application that you can find [here](https://sveltekit-template-theta.vercel.app/)

You can also find the full code [here](https://github.com/HuguesGallier/sveltekit-template)

My problem is the following: When I change the page, the new page gets appended to the end of the current page. When I refresh, the old page goes away.

The problem is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70051025/sveltekit-adds-new-page-on-top-of-old-one), but I do not use any loading indicator, and the proposed fixes did not work in my case.

Would anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Package versions:

```
"@sveltejs/kit": "^1.22.1",
"svelte": "^3.58.0",
"@auth/sveltekit": "^0.3.3",
```

`/+layout.svelte`

```
<script lang="ts">
 ... imports
</script> 

<div class="flex flex-col h-screen">
  <Drawer>
    <AvatarDropdown slot="user" />
    <div class="grow h-full" slot="content">
      <slot />
    </div>
  </Drawer>
</div>
```

`/dashboard/+layout.svelte`

```
<script>
  const user = $page.data.session?.user;
</script>

{#if user}
  <slot />
{:else}
  Please log in
{/if}
```

`/dashboard/+page.svelte`

```
<script>
  import { onDestroy } from "svelte";
</script>
<div
  class=""
  out:fade={{ duration: 0 }}
>
Content
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As described in [this old issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/628), transitions can mess up your UI.

Adding `|local` to your transition will solve the problem, like this:

```
<div out:fly|local={{ y: -200, duration: 500 }}>
    ...
</div>
```

Another "fix" can be to set `data-sveltekit-reload` in your link as described [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/link-options), but obviously you may not want to reload the page when a user clicks on the link.

Comment: You saved my life! how come this question didn't get more upvotes
Just for information, from svelte 4 onward local is the default directive for transitions, so I guess this issue must have been pretty common indeed